# Pull out the ID if last value on last 3 dates are less than 70

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to write an algorithm in python using pandas where I want to print the IDs if the Value of that id for last 3 consecutive days are less than 70.

In the given table as we see Value of A in last three dates (18/2/2019, 15/2/2020 and 16/2/2020)
are 76 , 89 and 77 respectively so It should not be printed but B (28/9/2017,27/2/2018 and 28/2/2018) are 23,24 and 25 which are less than 70 so it should be printed.

```
   id     Date      Value
0   A   15/2/2019   70
1   A   16/2/2019   72
2   A   17/2/2019   74
3   A   18/2/2019   76
4   A   15/2/2020   89
5   A   16/2/2020   77
6   B   20/1/2015   34
7   B   28/9/2017   23
8   B   27/2/2018   24
9   B   28/2/2018   25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `rolling`

```
s=df.Value.lt(70).groupby(df['id']).rolling(3).sum().groupby(level=0).last()
s.index[s==3]
Index(['B'], dtype='object', name='id')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: (x.tail(3)['Value'] < 70).all())['id'].unique()

array(['B'], dtype=object)
```